# OSX network sharing via multiple interfaces

Tags: macos, home-networking, connection-sharing

I have Mac mini with 3 interfaces; ppp0, ppp1 and en1 (Airport). I would like to direct all traffic from en1 to ppp1 while mini's own traffic would go to ppp0. How could I do this? I've tried to play with ipfw and natd but no luck so far.